# Need a RegEx that matches only a single instance of the pipe character

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a RegEx to only match instances of the 'pipe' character (|) that are NOT followed by one or more further pipes. So a pipe followed by anything other than a pipe.

I have this but it doesn't appear to be working:

```
/|(?!/|)
```

Comment: Update: This is matching pipes not followed by a pipe but I need it to also not match where there is a pipe BEFORE also.

\|(?!\|)

Answer (score 5):

You are escaping your `pipe` wrongly. You need to use `backslash`, and not `slash`. Apart from that, you also need to use `negative look-behind`, so that the `last` pipe is not matched, which is probably not preceded by a pipe, but not followed by it: -

```
(?<!\|)\|(?!\|)
```

Generally, I prefer to use character class rather than escaping if I want to match regex meta-character class: -

```
(?<![|])[|](?![|])
```

But, it's my taste.

Comment: Thanks! However this is now matching double pipes too. I only want to match a pipe not followed by a pipe.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I found the answer, after much iteration. This will match ONLY a single pipe character not proceeded AND not followed by a pipe.

```
(?=(\|(?!\|)))((?<!\|)\|)
```

Comment: This is the same as [Rohit's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14755645/20938), only less readable.  You should accept that one.

Answer (score 0):

Match a (start of line or a non-pipe) a pipe (an end of line or a non-pipe).

```
(^|[^|])[|]([^|]|$)
```